# Obtener campos relacionados con la consulta SQL no agregados

Tags: sql

Dada la consulta:

```
SELECT MAX(fecha), estado
FROM tabla
GROUP BY estado
```

Obtengo la fecha máxima de la tabla por cada estado.

Mi pregunta es: ¿Puedo obtener las columnas que no se encuentran en el Group By sin hacer agregaciones? es decir:

```
SELECT MAX(fecha), estado, id
FROM tabla
GROUP BY estado
```

Dónde me gustaría que el id fuera el id concreto de la row que se está seleccionando con `MAX(fecha)`.

Si la tabla `tabla` contiene:

> id - fecha - estado
>
> 1  - 11/03/1991 - Abierto
>
> 2  - 11/03/1992 - Abierto
>
> 3  - 11/03/1993 - Abierto
>
> 4  - 11/03/1992 - Cerrado
>
> 5  - 11/03/1991 - Cerrado

Si aplicara la primera consulta obtendría:

> 11/03/1993, Abierto
>
> 11/03/1992, Cerrado

Y me gustaría obtener:

> 11/03/1993, Abierto, 3
>
> 11/03/1992, Cerrado, 4

Entiendo que hay una problemática de más en el caso de que más de 1 fila tenga la misma fecha y estado, que provocaría que el id fuera *random* pero me serviría cualquiera. Es decir, si la tabla contiene:

> id - fecha - estado
>
> 1  - 11/03/1991 - Abierto
>
> 2  - 11/03/1992 - Abierto
>
> 3  - 11/03/1993 - Abierto
>
> 4  - 11/03/1992 - Cerrado
>
> 5  - 11/03/1991 - Cerrado
>
> 6  - 11/03/1992 - Cerrado

El resultado me sirve tanto este:

> 11/03/1993, Abierto, 3
>
> 11/03/1992, Cerrado, 4

Cómo este:

> 11/03/1993, Abierto, 3
>
> 11/03/1992, Cerrado, 6

Pero si hay alguna manera mejor de trabajar con ello me gustaría aprenderlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu primer consulta está perfecta, pero para recuperar el resto de los campos, tenés que hacer un `JOIN` con la tabla original.

```sql
SELECT tmax.*
FROM tabla tmax
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT MAX(fecha) max_fecha, estado
   FROM tabla
   GROUP BY estado) tgroup
ON 
  tmax.fecha = tgroup.max_fecha
  AND tmax.estado = tgroup.estado
GROUP BY tmax.estado;
```

<kbd>[Demo en SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f14b5/1/0)</kbd>

---

- Y si le quitamos el último `group by`, obtendríamos **todas** las filas que cumplen (aparecerían 2 filas con estado `Cerrado` que cumplen la condición -ya que son la misma con distinto ID).
  <sup>[(*comentado por el autor)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/32618?noredirect=1)</sup>

Comment: **Nota:** En sqlfiddle.com usé MySQL porque aparentemente no están funcionando el resto de los DBMS en la página, pero no influye en este caso.

Comment: Tu respuesta es 100% correcta :). Aún así me gustaría añadir que si le quitamos el último `group by` obtendría **todas** las filas que cumplen (aparecerían 2 filas con estado Cerrado que cumplen la condición - ya que son la misma con distinto ID).

Answer (score -1):

Esto ya depende de tu modelo de datos, pero si estás en el caso de que tu id es auto incremental, bastaría con hacer un `MAX(id)` y así obtendrías el último. De todas formas, el motor no te puede asegurar que el id recuperado concuerde con el `MAX(fecha)`.

Comment: Si hago un MAX(id) el resultado sería erróneo con la tabla que he planteado inicialmente ya que saldría el ID 5 en lugar del 4 para el Estado cerrado!